# How to make page number footer in the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, page-numbering

I have a class that contains a descrption of frontmatter and backmatter

You can consult the class by following this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdpd2134fzh8xcc/bredele.cls?dl=0).

How I can put the page number right in the footer, knowing that I tried to change the 'LE' and 'RO' indices, but it doesn't work. In the document, when I use *\frontmatter* and *\backmatter*, the page number style becomes *roman*, and I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. please give us a link to the class/template instead of posting a snippet. And never change a class file.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fancyhdr, you can use `\pagestyle{plain}` and

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{%
      \let\@oddhead\@empty
      \let\@evenhead\@empty
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: It workd! thank you, but can you give more details about what that did? Also I would like to use roman numbers for some pages and arabic for others, how can I make that?

Comment: I copied the definition of `\ps@plain` (from letter class) and removed the `\hfil` on the right side.  `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}`  Note that this affects \label and page number stored for use in the TOC.  And `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are used to allow @ symbols in macro names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want page numbers on the right of the pages use

```latex
\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
```

and if you want to make the front and back matter use arabic numbers then just toggle `\pagenumbering` as shown:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}

\cfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Some figures}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some figures}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\backmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Some figures}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```